# Can i use .env variables into a entity schema in typeorm?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

i have two entities that have a different schema than the others, and i set it straight in the entity.

But when i change the "schema string" to a .env variable, this return undefined, somebody know how set .env variable into a entities schema?

Comment: nodejs doesn't read .env files by default. You could use [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) lib for that

Comment: Are env variables working in other parts of the project? If not it's likely along the lines of what Micael said. Might be helpful to see some code.